# Why is newcommand not working?

Tags: macros, citing

I am quite new to latex and try to understand the `\newcommand` command. Since (at least in texmaker which I am using) `\autocite` does not seem to feature autocompletion and automated display of my bibliography like `\cite` does, I tried to shorten it up by using:

```
\newcommand{\citea[1]}{\autocite {#1}}
```

However using `\citea{ast_dual_2013}` leads to the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.43 \citea{ast_
dual_2013}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

`

This leads to a mathematical output:
[image: Latex output]

What can I do to improve the new defined command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first closing curly brace is too late, fixed:

```
\newcommand*{\citea}[1]{\autocite{#1}}
```